# Cells are not displaying correct name fetched from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

[image: One of the buster12's should be displaying a different users name, the correct ID is associated with that button and if I reload the table once more everything is fine, but it won't populate correctly the first time]

One of the buster12's should be displaying a different users name, the correct ID is associated with that button and if I reload the table once more everything is fine, but it won't populate correctly the first time.

I think I've narrowed it down a bit, so when I directly call for a list of matches from firebase using something like the function fetchMatches() below everything is fine. But when I first retrieve specific match IDs for a user then make another call for those matches, things don't work like for the function fetchMyMatches().

Here are my two functions getting data from Firebase:

```
func fetchMatches() {
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("completed_matches").queryLimited(toLast: 10)
        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                    let matchT = Match2()
                    let active = value["active"] as? Int ?? 0
                    let submitter = value["submitter"] as? Int ?? 0
                    let winner = value["winner"] as? Int ?? 0
                    let team_1_player_1 = value["team_1_player_1"] as? String ?? "Player not found"
                    let team_1_player_2 = value["team_1_player_2"] as? String ?? "Player not found"
                    let team_2_player_1 = value["team_2_player_1"] as? String ?? "Player not found"
                    let team_2_player_2 = value["team_2_player_2"] as? String ?? "Player not found"
                    let team1_scores = value["team1_scores"] as? [Int] ?? [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
                    let team2_scores = value["team2_scores"] as? [Int] ?? [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
                    let time = value["time"] as? Double ?? Date().timeIntervalSince1970
                    matchT.active = active
                    matchT.winner = winner
                    matchT.submitter = submitter
                    matchT.team_1_player_1 = team_1_player_1
                    matchT.team_1_player_2 = team_1_player_2
                    matchT.team_2_player_1 = team_2_player_1
                    matchT.team_2_player_2 = team_2_player_2
                    matchT.team1_scores = team1_scores
                    matchT.team2_scores = team2_scores
                    matchT.matchId = snapshot.key
                    matchT.time = time
                    self.matches.append(matchT)
                    self.matches = self.matches.sorted { p1, p2 in
                        return (p1.time!) > (p2.time!)
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData()}
                }
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }

    func fetchMyMatches() {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            return
        }
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("user_matches").child(uid)
        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            let matchId = snapshot.key
            let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
            let query = rootRef.child("matches").child(matchId)
            query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                print(snapshot)
                if let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                    let matchT = Match2()
                    let active = value["active"] as? Int ?? 0
                    let submitter = value["submitter"] as? Int ?? 0
                    let winner = value["winner"] as? Int ?? 0
                    let team_1_player_1 = value["team_1_player_1"] as? String ?? "Player not found"
                    let team_1_player_2 = value["team_1_player_2"] as? String ?? "Player not found"
                    let team_2_player_1 = value["team_2_player_1"] as? String ?? "Player not found"
                    let team_2_player_2 = value["team_2_player_2"] as? String ?? "Player not found"
                    let team1_scores = value["team1_scores"] as? [Int] ?? [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
                    let team2_scores = value["team2_scores"] as? [Int] ?? [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
                    let time = value["time"] as? Double ?? Date().timeIntervalSince1970
                    matchT.active = active
                    matchT.winner = winner
                    matchT.submitter = submitter
                    matchT.team_1_player_1 = team_1_player_1
                    matchT.team_1_player_2 = team_1_player_2
                    matchT.team_2_player_1 = team_2_player_1
                    matchT.team_2_player_2 = team_2_player_2
                    matchT.team1_scores = team1_scores
                    matchT.team2_scores = team2_scores
                    matchT.matchId = snapshot.key
                    matchT.time = time
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.matches.append(matchT)
                        self.matches = self.matches.sorted { p1, p2 in
                            return (p1.time!) > (p2.time!)
                        }
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            })
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
```

Comment: That tableView: cellForRowAt has a lot of repeating code. And too many different options , which of the 17 exits is failing?

Comment: @Maetschl I edited it to be more concise, so cell.challengerteam1 etc. are where I am setting the names of the cells, I have to fetch the names from Firebase and I think that it's taking too long is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, maybe it wasn't clear. In Firebase callback, it stores data, then reload the data and the cell will be filled with the same object you filled before. right?
In addition to this, please add again how you are instantiating the cell.

Comment: @Maetschl Ok I added the instantiation line of code. For some reason when I reload the data it just won't reload it right unless I were to call it a bit later, or scroll up and down the cells then it fixes itself

Comment: @Maetschl I updated the specific problem as I think I've narrowed it down

Answer (score 0):

Sure you're using

`dequeueReusableCell`

Without implement `override prepareForReuse`

There you can reset information for fix issues of `real time` implementation.

When you scroll effectively the cell it's created again and that probably refreshes the data.

Another solution instantiates a new cell again every time but has a low performance.

Check this tutorial: https://medium.com/ios-seminar/why-we-use-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-ce7fd97cde8e

Comment: That's not quite the problem I'm having, the reused cells are actually populating correctly, it's the initial cells that don't populate correctly.